# Could not load file or assembly (run-time error)

Tags: c#

I placed a dll file in the bin folder of a class library project and added a reference to it. Added namespace but when I am creating object of a class of this dll it is giving me run time error -

> Could not load file or assembly 'dll name' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I tried using the below code to load the dll:

```
 Assembly MyDALL =  Assembly.LoadFile("Test.dll");
 Type MyLoadClass = MyDALL.GetType("Test.Class1");
 object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(MyLoadClass);
```

Now it looks for its dependent dll in given error again.

Any solution to this?

Comment: Which part of the error message are you struggling to understand? The file is obviously not were you are trying to load it from

Comment: Did you try using Dependency Walker to determine the name of the missing dll?

Comment: Try giving a absolute path instead of just a file name. also look up if you set the "copy local"-attribute under properties for this assembly

Comment: Is it a mixed mode C++/CLI dll? If so, you're probably missing a C++ dependent dll or a C++ runtime.

Comment: Try using ` Assembly.LoadFrom` which probes the dependent assembly and load into appdomain if found.

Comment: are you running the project within Visual Studio? (using F5 or Shift + F5)

Answer (score 0):

You should try to load the .dll from the directory you are running your application in. You can get that from code using:

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)
```

Note that if you put your .dll in the `/bin` directory, it might get overwritten next time you compile your application.

You might be better off including it into the project, and then marking it for output by right clicking it in the Solution Explorer, selecting **Properties**, and setting **Copy to Output Directory** to *Copy Always* or *Copy if newer*.

That way it will be published to your `/bin` directory automatically.